# Why does $.each loop through an element correct but not for the second one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of rows with product informations and I want to get the title, produtc id and price. When I loop through all with $.each it does work for title and product id, but not for price. I get always all prices for every row. Here is my code:

```
<tr id="ric685197870" class="n_ListTab1 ric_art">
            <td class="n_ListPic"><img title="Das Angebot verfügt über ein Bild." alt="Das Angebot verfügt über ein Bild." src="https://pics.ricardostatic.ch/ImgWeb/2/V3/listing/img.gif"></td>
            <td class="n_ListIcons"><a title="Das Angebot endet in weniger als 3 Stunden." href="javascript:help('symbol_uebersicht')"><span class="sprite icon_3h"></span></a></td>
            <td class="n_ListTitle"><a class="entry-title" href="http://www.ricardo.ch/kaufen/buecher-und-comics/belletristik/sonstige/ich-jagte-eichmann-s-wiesenthal/v/an685197870/" title="Ich jagte Eichmann/S.Wiesenthal">Ich jagte Eichmann/S.Wiesenthal</a></td>
            <td class="n_ListDate">11.9.2012 11:00</td>
            <td class="n_ListOffer">0</td>
            <td class="n_ListPrice">
            <div class="Auc">
                <span class="currency">CHF </span>0.10
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ric686793488" class="n_ListTab2 ric_art">
            <td class="n_ListPic"><img title="Das Angebot verfügt über ein Bild." alt="Das Angebot verfügt über ein Bild." src="https://pics.ricardostatic.ch/ImgWeb/2/V3/listing/img.gif"></td>
            <td class="n_ListIcons"><a title="Das Angebot endet in weniger als 3 Stunden." href="javascript:help('symbol_uebersicht')"><span class="sprite icon_3h"></span></a></td>
            <td class="n_ListTitle"><a class="entry-title" href="http://www.ricardo.ch/kaufen/buecher-und-comics/belletristik/romane/sonstige/angelika-overath-alle-farben-des-schnees/v/an686793488/" title="Angelika Overath: Alle Farben des Schnees">Angelika Overath: Alle Farben des Schnees</a></td>
            <td class="n_ListDate">11.9.2012 11:02</td>
            <td class="n_ListOffer">1</td>
            <td class="n_ListPrice">
               <div class="Auc">
                  <span class="currency">CHF </span>4.00
               </div></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.each($(".n_ListTitle"), function(i, v) {
            var node = $(this);
            var nodeParent = node.parent();
            var nodeText = node.text();
            var nodePrice = nodeParent.children(i)[5];

            var prodPrice = $(nodePrice.nodeName + ' div').text();
            var prodId = nodeParent.attr('id').replace('ric', '');
            var prodTitle = nodeText;

            var json = {
                id : prodId,
                price : prodPrice,
                currency : "CHF",
                name : prodTitle
            };
            console.log(json);
        });
```

I get this:

> Object
>   currency: "CHF"
>   id: "681625138"
>   name: "BEVERLEY HARPER: HELLER MOND IN SCHWARZER NACHT--TASCHENBUCH"
>   price: " **here is the problem: every price in every row** "

I hope it is understandable and I hope someone can help me to figure out. thanks!

Comment: Nope, I still didn't get what you mean by 'every price in every row'

Comment: Your problem is this line `nodeParent.children(i)[5]` it doesn't make any sense. `i` is a dom element, and .children expects a selector. `[5]` doesn't really make sense either.

Comment: @KevinB: `i` is actually the index in the "array".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var prodPrice =  $(nodePrice.nodeName + ' div').text();
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  `nodePrice.nodeName` is `"tr"`, so your selector is:

```
$('tr div')
```

So, you're getting all the prices, since you are selecting every `div` that is a child of a `tr`.

What you really want is this:

```
var prodPrice = $('div', nodePrice).text();
```

This is equivalent to `$(nodePrice).find('div')`

Also:

```
var nodePrice = nodeParent.children(i)[5];
```

Why are you passing the `i` here?  `i` is the index in the "array", it won't be of any use to `.children`.  You want to use this:

```
var nodePrice = nodeParent.children().eq(5);
```

Or, better yet (you have these classes, let's use 'em):

```
var nodePrice = node.siblings('.n_ListPrice');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! This is understandable and it does work well now :)

Comment: @MarcoCiarfaglia Make sure you mark his answer as accepted, it helps both you and the person who answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var nodePrice = node.siblings(".n_ListPrice");
```

then you can extract the actual price using

```
$(nodePrice).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for arrays ([jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)):

```
$.each($(".n_ListTitle"), function(i, v) {
```

You need ([.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)):

```
$(".n_ListTitle").each(function(i, v) {
```

Comment: The result of a selector *is* an array.

Comment: `$.each` will handle a jQuery object just fine.

Comment: @TimRogers the result of a selector is an array-like object, not an array. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var nodePrice = nodeParent.find('.n_ListPrice div');
var prodPrice = nodePrice.text();
```

Prefer using another selector than `eq(5)` if you decide to add a row later you will have to change all this... Use `find()` to find the TD with the class of the priceholder and select the div inside it. There you go :)